# Jquery ajax succes not working completeley

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working on a notification system and i am having problemsremoving classes or doing anything other than html() and append() in ajax success. here is my code:

```
    setInterval(function (){
    $(".notificare_caseta").each(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("record");
        $.ajax({
            url : "../template/functions/notificari.php?nr="+id,                          
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"JSON",                   
            success : function(data) {  
                $(".notificari_zona"+id).html(data.notif);
                if(data.note>0){
                    $(".notificari_note"+id).html(data.note);
                }else{
                    $(".notificari_note"+id).addClass('nu_arata');
                    $(".notificari_note"+id).prev().removeClass("atentionare");
                    $(".notificari_note"+id).next().addClass("nu_arata");
                }
            }
        });                 
    });

    $("#data").load("../template/functions/data.php");

}, 2000);
```

Anyone is able to help me? the next, prev, removeclass, addclass functions not working. Thanks

Comment: "Not working" is not very descriptive. What do they do instead of the expected behaviour?

Comment: the only working part in the success code is the html()/append()(not present int this code). the nex(), prev(), addClass(), removeClass() simply dont work. How can i compose a more specific title?

Comment: But what happens instead? Are you sure `data.note` is ever `<=0`?

Comment: yes. my php file returns the rowcount of notifications for a specific id. it can never be less than 0. the only thing tha happens is tha my script only adds/doesnt add(else) my html data to my element.

Comment: Are you sure the `else` clause is ever reached. E.g., set a breakpoint at the first line in your success function and step through it to see what happens.

Comment: it works. ive put html(data.note) in my els cluase and it shows 0; the problem appers alos in the main if clause.

Comment: Then still you should put a breakpoint and step through the code to see what happens, e.g., does it manipulate the DOM correctly. It's hard to guess what's wrong this way.

Comment: ive tried different optinos, same result. I'm guessiing its the each() function wohs responsible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your function of sending data and getting back.

```
setInterval(function (){
    var ids = [];
    $(".notificare_caseta").each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).attr("record"));
    });
    $.ajax({
        url : "notificari.php",
        data : {"nr":ids},
        dataType:"JSON",
        success : function(data) {  
            //here you should get the all data togther for ex [{"notif":1,"note":1},{"notif":2,"note":2},{"notif":3,"note":3}]
            $.each(data,function(i,x){
                $(".notificari_zona"+ids[x]).html(i.notif);
                if(i.note>0){
                    $(".notificari_note"+ids[x]).html(i.note);
                }else{
                    modify(".notificari_note"+ids[x]);
                }
            })
        }
    });                 


    // $("#data").load("../template/functions/data.php");

}, 10000);
```

Comment: ive checked the console, no errors. the jSON encoding is corect. and since the data is outputted to my page i think its sent right. I still cant wrap my head arround the problem....

Comment: i think then you ve to be paste down the response you are getting. I need to see the response.

Comment: whatresponse? i mean from where?

Comment: If you are using firefox use firebug and see the response. if chrome see the response in network tools

Comment: here is the respons for one of the elements that im updating: {"notif":1,"note":1}

Comment: are u sure u getting that response? or send me the code i ll check it

Comment: im sending you he php html and js

Comment: please leave an email i cannot send it here. Thanks

Comment: see i need to see the data u r sending. maybe there is the problem in getting data.. ur code seems to be ok but i dont know what u r getting in response. if u can give a snapshot of ur network response in chrome or firefox.

Comment: i think  got the problem. you ve to remove each function from your settimeout function. it sends alot of request so the response is not handled properly. send all the id together and then get the response in multidimensional array in json and then parse it once.

Comment: thanks but work on my last comment i posted. u r sending many requests once. u should limit to one request by sending all together.

Comment: ive placed the functions separately outside the interval function. still the same problem As for the number of requests, i think is a bit hard to do, and i would still need alot of passes. (3 foreach one in another) just to count the rows notifications for one "zona". I will try this too but a bit later.

Comment: do you have any other solutions? even if i make just one request its the same problem

Comment: i did like you said; got all the info in one pass, with one ajax load....still the same problem..

Comment: Hey its working fine in my browser. I think you are not getting right encoding back from the server and you are still not sending one request. if there are 5 of these notificare_caseta elements then you will make the request five times. you should avoid that.

Comment: I have rewritten the function for you. I am pasting in my reply above

Comment: same problem:(. i'd put it on the each function.

Comment: it's the prev/next functions. i think i know why theydont work but i cant really explain why... maybe beacuse the preveious element has a class used by more than one element. It works if i modify the classes to be unique... but its not realy that efficient..